# Template argument deduction for array types

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Microsoft VC++ 2010 gives an error on this code:

```
template <int D, typename T>
void Foo(T x[D]) {
  // details omitted
}

int main() {
  float x[3];
  Foo(x);  // C2784: could not deduce template argument for 'T [D]' from 'float [3]'
  return 0;
}
```

The same code passes muster with gcc and clang.

Is this a bug with VC++ 2010?

If it is a bug:

1. Does anyone know if it's been fixed in a later version of VC++?
2. Is there a workaround besides explicitly calling `Foo<3, float>`?

If it is not a bug:

Is there an extension to gcc and clang that allows them to resolve the template arguments?

I've greatly simplified the actual code down to this small example.  I've tried it on other compilers, but I don't presently have access to newer Microsoft compilers.  I've found similar questions on SO, but none that specifically address this case.

Comment: with 'Visual Studio 2013' and 'Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP' I get the same error.

Comment: Doesn't compile with clang for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918ee9e151031a46 -- Nor gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0399a5aff6ce0f83

Comment: Ah, sorry about the gcc and clang red-herring.  They were accepting a more complicated version of Foo, apparently because they were able to deduce the parameters from the second argument.  But MS VC++ wasn't accepting the more complex version.  Because the complex version was too long to post, I simplified down to this but didn't actually test my last iterations on gcc and clang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A parameter of type `T x[D]` is equivalent to `T x[]` aka `T* x`. `D` cannot be deduced from it. Make it `void Foo(T (&x)[D])` - you are passing a reference to an array this way.

Comment: I don't know how template param deduction works here, but `T x[]` is not the same type as `T *x`. And why does it work in gcc and clang?

Comment: @bolov: Yes it is the same, in parameter lists (you can't pass arrays by value).  And no it does not work in gcc and clang, at least not for me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Again, I don't know about template deduction here, so lets forget for a second about templates. `int x[]` is NOT the same type as `int *x`. `int *x` is a pointer, whereas `int x[]` is an incomplete type of an array type. They are convertible between each other, but they are not the same types. Now I was wrong in the past, but I am pretty sure I am right on this one. Could you provide an explanation why I am wrong?

Comment: @bolov They are the same when used for a parameter in function declaration. You can even declare a function one way, and define it the other: `void f(int* x); void f(int x[]) {...}` Thank C heritage for that.

Comment: @bolov: In a normal declaration, you are right, they are not the same. However, as a function parameter, you cannot pass arrays by value. And so, in what I consider an error in language design, C (and by extension, C++), causes a parameter declaration that *looks* like an array to actually be a pointer. So, as a parameter, `int *x` is the same as `int x[]`, and it's the same as `int x[100]`, and it's the same as `int x[9999999]`. Again, this is *only* for parameters. You are right to point out that arrays are not pointers, keep doing that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you. I didn't know that. I thought a conversion is performed when a pointer is passed to a parameter of array type.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley How about `int x[][10]`? Since it cannot be the same as `int **` (different levels of indirections), or as `int (*x)[]`. Because if the real type is `int **` (what you pass as a parameter) dereferencing it, i.e. `x[2][3]` should be equivalent with `*(*(x+2) + 3)`

Comment: @bolov: As a parameter, that would be a pointer to an array of 10 ints. Same as `int (*x)[10]`

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thanks.